# PHP variable inside jQuery variable not working

Tags: php, jquery

I have a jquery var endDate that stores a date to countdown to.

```
var endDate = "August 14, 2014 20:30:00";
```

The countdown works fine like this.

When I add the php variable to it, the countdown date is set to 00 00 00 NaN

```
$rebuyDayCountdown = date('F d, Y H:i:s',strtotime($resultRBD['rebuyDay']));
// outputs -> August 14, 2014 20:30:00

var endDate = "<?php echo $rebuyDayCountdown; ?>";
```

What is wrong? Does it have something to do with the double quotes?

EDIT: more code provided.

NOTE: my jquery is in another file linked into the php file

```
$sqlRBD = " SELECT gameTime, DATE_ADD(gameTime,INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS rebuyDay FROM ( ";
$sqlRBD .= "    SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE weekNumber = " . $week . " ORDER BY gameTime DESC ";
$sqlRBD .= ") x GROUP BY weekNumber ";

$queryRBD = mysql_query($sqlRBD);

while ($resultRBD = mysql_fetch_array($queryRBD)) {

    $rebuyDay = $resultRBD['rebuyDay'];
    $rebuyDayCountdown = date('F d, Y H:i:s',strtotime($resultRBD['rebuyDay']));
}
```

I have echo out both $rebuyDay (2014-08-14 20:30:00) and $rebuyDayCountdown (August 14, 2014 20:30:00) fine.

jquery code below

This first set of code works fine.

```
//countdown for rebuy button
$(function() {

    // set the date to countdown too
    var endDate = "August 14, 2014 20:30:00";

    $('#rebuy-countdown').countdown({

        date: endDate,

        render: function(data) {

            $(this.el).html("<li class='counter-numbers'>" + this.leadingZeros(data.days, 2) + " <span class='counter-label'>days</span></li><li class='counter-numbers'>" + this.leadingZeros(data.hours, 2) + " <span class='counter-label'>hours</span></li><li class='counter-numbers'>" + this.leadingZeros(data.min, 2) + " <span class='counter-label'>minutes</span></li><li class='counter-numbers'>" + this.leadingZeros(data.sec, 2) + " <span class='counter-label'>seconds</span></li>");

        }
    });
});
```

This set does not work and sets date to 00 00 00 Nan

```
//countdown for rebuy button
$(function() {

    // set the date to countdown too
    var endDate = "<?php echo $rebuyDayCountdown; ?>";

    $('#rebuy-countdown').countdown({

        date: endDate,

        render: function(data) {

            $(this.el).html("<li class='counter-numbers'>" + this.leadingZeros(data.days, 2) + " <span class='counter-label'>days</span></li><li class='counter-numbers'>" + this.leadingZeros(data.hours, 2) + " <span class='counter-label'>hours</span></li><li class='counter-numbers'>" + this.leadingZeros(data.min, 2) + " <span class='counter-label'>minutes</span></li><li class='counter-numbers'>" + this.leadingZeros(data.sec, 2) + " <span class='counter-label'>seconds</span></li>");

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What is  the value of `$resultRBD['rebuyDay']`? Is it set?

Comment: @andrewsi yes $resultRBD['rebuyDay'] is set. It equals to 2014-08-14 20:30:00

Comment: The part of code you posted seems to be working just fine. I would say that the problem is with the rest of your JS code: can you post it?

Comment: This. Either the rest of the JS code is faulty, or `$rebuyDayCountdown` isn't `August 14, 2014 20:30:00` like you expect. Post more code, please

Comment: The error is not in the JS code because it works fine with a hardcoded value. Error most probably comes from PHP value not being what's expected

Comment: Q: Those two lines of code; they're not in your code like that, are they? Surely, you're seperating PHP from JS, correct? @user2759965

Comment: if `$resultRBD['rebuyDay']` contains `2014-08-14 20:30:00`, as the OP said, the PHP part should work just fine (and it does). That's why I would say that there's something weird going on with the JS. Seems like the OP's going to post the JS part as well, let's wait :)

Comment: Are u sure JS is not reading it as it is (string) "<?php echo $rebuyDayCountdown; ?>". 

how about:
<script ...>
var endDate = <?php echo $rebuyDayCountdown; ?>
</script>

Comment: Yes php and jquery are separate. PHP is in a php file, jquery is in a js file.

Comment: Can you enter an `alert(endDate);` and tell us what's in there?

Comment: Then as previously stated, try `var endDate = <?php echo $rebuyDayCountdown; ?>;` without the quotes, see if that makes it kick in.

Comment: alert(endDate) is <?php echo $rebuyDayCountdown; ?>

Comment: ...and/or changing `$rebuyDayCountdown = date('F d, Y H:i:s',strtotime($resultRBD['rebuyDay']));` to `$rebuyDayCountdown = date('F d, Y H:i:s',strtotime($rebuyDay));`

Comment: The problem seems to be that endDate value is <?php echo $rebuyDayCountdown; ?> and not the value of the php variable

Comment: What is your column type set to?

Comment: gameTime is set to datetime and rebuyDay was created on the fly with DATE_ADD(gameTime,INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS rebuyDay

Comment: Wait, are you saying that endDate contains the string "<?php echo $rebuyDayCountdown; ?>"?

Comment: yes its a string and not the php value

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a javascript variable of type `Date` instead?
You can do that using:

`var endDate = new Date('<?php echo $rebuyDayCountdown; ?>');`

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? What's the output?

Comment: The output of the countdown date is set to 00 00 00 NaN and when I do an alert(endDate) I get a value of invalid date